# Imported String from Database has quotes("), want to use String to Query Database again

Tags: java, sql, regex, double-quotes

So I have a script that retrieves a list of items that were used on a product within a time period. Our database is 'jerry-rigged', so to say, where we do not have these items listed as their code, but by a description. I can run this description through another table on our database to retrieve an item code, but I run into an issue with items that have a double quote in them, like '2" Self Tapping Screw', where the double quotes causes an issue with my query. Below are the issue lines I have:

```
String description = resultSet.getString(1); //description = "2" Self Tapping Screw
String sql = "Select itemcode from database.table where description " 
    + "= \"" + description + "\";
```

How can I replace these double quotes with the regex character? I tried

```
description = description.replace("\"","\\"");
```

but I do not think I am getting it right, because it just changes every '"' to "\".

Comment: Use prepared statement with parametrized `sql`

Comment: This looks like a job for prepared statements and query parameters.  Treating input values as executable code causes a lot of unnecessary problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("<Your connection string>");
String sql = "Select itemcode from database.table where description = ?";
PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement(sql);
prep.setString(1,  resultSet.getString(1));
prep.executeUpdate();
```

This is much safer than trying to escape Strings by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, issue is gone!